# Problem with JOINT data : An array literal was missing values

Tags: google-sheets-formula

My formula is working fine as below:

`=QUERY({QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM","mid!A3:H"),"Select Col4,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6 where Col4 ='"&B9&"'");QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM","mid!A3:H"),"Select Col4,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6 where Col4 ='"&B10&"'");QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM","mid!A3:H"),"Select Col4,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6 where Col4 ='"&B13&"'");QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM","mid!A3:H"),"Select Col4,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6 where Col4 ='"&B14&"'")},"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

That formula will do Query base on value of B9 to B14;

BUT there is an `ERROR " An array literal was missing values for one or more rows"` when formula was changed, example B14 to B13 or B14 to B12, It means we can not query base on any value of B12 and B13.

Any one know where is problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are getting the error because one of your `QYERY`s returns nothing (`#N/A`) which is 1 column wide but others are 5 column wide.

Try another approach, filtering in a single query.

Using regular expressions:

```
=QUERY(
  IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM", "mid!A3:H"),
  "SELECT Col4, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6
   WHERE     Col1 IS NOT NULL
         AND Col4 MATCHES '^(?:" & TEXTJOIN("|", 1, {B9, B10, B13, B14}) & ")$'"
)
```

Using plain `OR`:

```
=QUERY(
  IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM", "mid!A3:H"),
  "SELECT Col4, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6
   WHERE     Col1 IS NOT NULL
         AND (   Col4 = '" & B9 & "'
              OR Col4 = '" & B10 & "'
              OR Col4 = '" & B13 & "'
              OR Col4 = '" & B14 & "')"
)
```

Also having less `IMPORTRANGE` calls is better.

Comment: thanks it works fine, i think my problem due to many importRange was called

Comment: by the way, I have question to limit return query value when i use your regular expressions, It mean I want B9,B10,B11,, return value only 1 row base on condition Desc or Asc: =QUERY(
  IMPORTRANGE("15TJp3b7-4clk49P4msiS92RHHidY3nyhyjtS5MvLLDM", "mid!A3:H"),
  "SELECT Col4, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6
   WHERE     Col1 IS NOT NULL
         AND Col4 MATCHES '^(?:" & TEXTJOIN("|", 1, {B9, B10, B13, B14}) & ")$' Order by Col3 Desc limit 1"), But seem they not work because they return 1 row only.

Comment: @TuPHAN getting 1 row while using `LIMIT 1` is the correct behavior. I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Please prepare a separate question and an example sheet shared with editing permissions.

Comment: File are big and many data, will try to make a copy sample soon. And if without LIMIT there are too many data return; what I want to achieve is each data when Col4 matches B9,...B14 will return only 1 row order by Asc or Desc.

Comment: Here is link, sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j5gz7Ad5YyIQQyZ_0TiDG1jPIElTW_fvfnBoz_y_ebY/edit?usp=sharing